# Class variable in a class of itself C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a class called `Node`:

```cpp
class Node {
    private:
    Node right;
    Node left;
    std::string value;
    public:
    Node(Node right, Node left, std::string value) {
        this->right = right;
        this->left = left;
        this->value = value;
    }
};
```

And I need to declare a private variable of type Node inside the Node class itself.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Think of how big Node will be if each Node contains 2 Nodes. The answer is infinite.

Comment: It would end up with some Node types being NULL.

Comment: ***Is there any way to do this?*** You need to use a pointer or better yet a smart pointer.

Comment: ***It would end up with some Node types being NULL*** Without a pointer there is no NULL concept. In your code each Node has 2 full Nodes which can not be NULL.

Comment: @lowlevellarry, While some languages will automatically make things pointers under the hood and avoid special syntax, C++ doesn't. You need to specify a pointer explicitly if you want a pointer or else you get an in-place object.

Comment: *'or better yet a smart pointer'* – depends... Smart pointers allow for nicely cleaning up an entire (sub-) tree if deleted. On the other hand we then need to explicitly clear the smart pointers if just deleting one single node while the two child branches are re-organised. So the benefit of the smart pointers might be questionable in some cases. Statically allocated trees get impossible as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare the members as being *pointers* to `Node` instances. Especially since you want to be able to set them to `NULL`, which can only be done with pointers:

```cpp
class Node {
    private:
    Node* right;
    Node* left;
    std::string value;
    public:
    Node(Node* right, Node* left, std::string value) {
        this->right = right;
        this->left = left;
        this->value = value;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to declare a class with itself as a member like this, you need to use pointers to do so. If you didn't need pointers, then creating one node object would construct two node members, both of which have their own node members which would construct more nodes and so on. By using pointers, you effectively must explicitly link each pointer member to an object in the heap, which prevents an immediate stack overflow error.

```
class Node {
   private:
   Node* right;
   Node* left;
   std::string value;
   public:
   Node(Node right, Node left, std::string value) {
      this.right = new Node(right.data);
      this.left = new Node(left.data);
      this.value = value;
   }
   ~Node(){ delete left; delete right; }
};
```

Here's an example of how this might look. This won't compile as-is, but its a representation of the right idea. Make sure to initialze left or right to nullptr unless you explicitly assign it in construction and specify a destructor like in this example. Also don't forget "the big three" if needed.

Note that I changed your shorthand to a dot operator, as in `this.right`. Your compiler will probably understand what you mean, but the shorthand should only be used when accessing a pointers data, such as in something like `right->data`. In case you didn't know, `right->data` actually does the exact same thing as `(*right).data`. We use a shorthand operator because `*right.data` would fail because the dot operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator.

Comment: You could also use references, but reference members cannot be re-assigned, making for an extremely limited linked list. Reference members do have their uses, just not here.